# Strange highlights and weird colors on model

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light

I created a model and added some lighting. it is a human model and so it has subsurface scattering. For some reason, there are two strange problems, and I am unsure if they are related or not, so I decided to keep them in the same thread. For one, there are some strange quick color switches (on the belt) and I am unsure of why it changes shades so much and without any gradient in the middle. The other issue is on the skin, near other objects, such as the hair, clothing, or eyes. I have smooth shading on, but with it off, the same results occur I will add some screenshots.

You can see the weird highlights on the belt and around the eyes best. 
[image: Render]

these are the nodes for the red cloth. They are grouped with the black cloth (which has no visible problems)
[image: Material Nodes for the Red Cloth]

These are the nodes for the skin material
[image: Material Nodes for the Skin]

Thank you so much!

Comment: Is it possible the normals on the belt are inverted?

Comment: No, none of the normals are inverted

Comment: On closer inspection, I suspect the image plugged into both the normal and height inputs of the bump node may have something to do with it. If you only plug it into the height input, does that help?